# select the values from the postgresql database and insert/update based on that i need complete query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to design this in query level is this possible to do for version,deleted,flag columns in the table.

src_emp----> source table

```
empno,ename,sal
1    ,aaa  ,1000
2    ,bbb  ,2000
3    ,ccc  ,3000
```

First load in target table trg_emp output look like below

```
empkey,empno,ename,sal  ,version,flag,deleted
1     ,1    ,aaa  ,1000 ,1      ,Y   ,N
2     ,2    ,bbb  ,2000 ,1      ,Y   ,N
3     ,3    ,ccc  ,3000 ,1      ,Y   ,N
```

Now after doing this i will change the salary for empno=3 to sal=4000 
Then after updating my target table look like

```
empkey,empno,ename,sal  ,version,flag,deleted
1     ,1    ,aaa  ,1000 ,1      ,Y   ,N
2     ,2    ,bbb  ,2000 ,1      ,Y   ,N
3     ,3    ,ccc  ,3000 ,1      ,N   ,N
4     ,3    ,ccc  ,4000 ,2      ,Y   ,N
```

Above you can observe version is increased to 2 for empno=3  and flag has changed for last row to "Y" and previous row as "N" for the empno=3
Ok once version and flag works then third is deleted if any record is deleted in source then that flag has to become 'Y'
Suppose if i delete empno=2 in source table
then my final target table should look like below format

```
empkey,empno,ename,sal,version,flag,deleted
1,1,aaa,1000,1,Y,N
2,2,bbb,2000,1,Y,Y
3,3,ccc,3000,1,N,N
4,3,ccc,4000,2,Y,N
```

In target table second row flag has to update deleted flag value as "Y".

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Are you attempting to use the first and third listing to get the last listing? Also are you really using both mysql and postgresql?

Comment: I agree with Conrad Frix.  I can't understand what you are asking, or what you are trying to accomplish here.  You should clearly state your problem, any errors you are getting and what technologies (and version) you are using.

Comment: If this is how that table should always be modified, I would use stored procedures to do the job. (Are they call *stored functions* in PostgreSQL?) Anyway, I'm seconding @Conrad's question about whether you need this in MySQL as well as in PostgreSQL. Have you added the `mysql` tag by mistake perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can force that kind of behavior by using TRIGGERS using postgresql.
You have to create a trigger in the table referencing to the trigger function.

More info on creating triggers here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

and info on creating triggers functions here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: By mistake i have added mysql i need in amazon redshift it wont support any triggers or procedures.. Postgre and reshift both are same only the difference is triggers and procedures are not available.. thats y i mentioned it as a postgresql

Comment: After reading your comment several times I still can't understand what do you want... Be more clear in what database you're using and what problems do you face, in a readable English please.